# My tool site is indexed but not ranking on Google which is 1 year and 164 days old

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-results, google-ranking

I have a tool site, which is created by me and published before 1 year. The site is available on Google. But till now the site is not ranking on Google. On the other hand, My tool sites are ranked in Bing in the **first and third positions**. 
Why my site is not ranking on Google?